# NLTK RegEx Chunker not capturing defined grammar patterns with wildcards

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, text-chunking

I am trying to chunk a sentence using NLTK's POS tags as regular expressions. 2 rules are defined to identify phrases, based on the tags of words in the sentence.

Mainly, I wanted to capture the chunk of **one or more verbs followed by an optional determiner and then one or more nouns at the end**. This is the first rule in definition. But it is not getting captured as Phrase Chunk.

```
import nltk

## Defining the POS tagger 
tagger = nltk.data.load(nltk.tag._POS_TAGGER)


## A Single sentence - input text value
textv="This has allowed the device to start, and I then see glitches which is not nice."
tagged_text = tagger.tag(textv.split())

## Defining Grammar rules for  Phrases
actphgrammar = r"""
     Ph: {<VB*>+<DT>?<NN*>+}  # verbal phrase - one or more verbs followed by optional determiner, and one or more nouns at the end
     {<RB*><VB*|JJ*|NN*\$>} # Adverbial phrase - Adverb followed by adjective / Noun or Verb
     """

### Parsing the defined grammar for  phrases
actp = nltk.RegexpParser(actphgrammar)

actphrases = actp.parse(tagged_text)
```

The input to the chunker, tagged_text is as below.

> tagged_text
>   Out[7]: 
>   [('This', 'DT'),
>    ('has', 'VBZ'),
>    ('allowed', 'VBN'),
>    ('the', 'DT'),
>    ('device', 'NN'),
>    ('to', 'TO'),
>    ('start,', 'NNP'),
>    ('and', 'CC'),
>    ('I', 'PRP'),
>    ('then', 'RB'),
>    ('see', 'VB'),
>    ('glitches', 'NNS'),
>    ('which', 'WDT'),
>    ('is', 'VBZ'),
>    ('not', 'RB'),
>    ('nice.', 'NNP')]

In the final output, only the adverbial phrase ('**then see**'), that is matching the second rule is being captured.
I expected the verbal phrase ('**allowed the device**') to match with the first rule and get captured as well, but its not.

> actphrases Out[8]: Tree('S', [('This', 'DT'), ('has', 'VBZ'),
>   ('allowed', 'VBN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('device', 'NN'), ('to', 'TO'),
>   ('start,', 'NNP'), ('and', 'CC'), ('I', 'PRP'), ***Tree('Ph', [('then',
>   'RB'), ('see', 'VB')])***, ('glitches', 'NNS'), ('which', 'WDT'), ('is',
>   'VBZ'), ('not', 'RB'), ('nice.', 'NNP')])

NLTK version used is 2.0.5 (Python 2.7)
Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Bala.

Comment: First update your NLTK to 3.1. There's significant changes made since 2.0 and it's necessary to get working code. `sudo apt-get install python-nltk` or `sudo pip install -U nltk`. Then take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090734/how-to-use-nltk-regex-pattern-to-extract-a-specific-phrase-chunk/34093919#34093919

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close but minor changes to your regex will get you your desired output. When you want to get a wildcard using `RegexpParser` grammar, you should use `.*` instead of `*`, e.g. `VB.*` instead of `VB*`:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, RegexpParser
>>> text = "This has allowed the device to start, and I then see glitches which is not nice."
>>> tagged_text = pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))    
>>> g = r"""
... VP: {<VB.*><DT><NN.*>}
... """
>>> p = RegexpParser(g); p.parse(tagged_text)
Tree('S', [('This', 'DT'), ('has', 'VBZ'), Tree('VP', [('allowed', 'VBN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('device', 'NN')]), ('to', 'TO'), ('start', 'VB'), (',', ','), ('and', 'CC'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('then', 'RB'), ('see', 'VBP'), ('glitches', 'NNS'), ('which', 'WDT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('not', 'RB'), ('nice', 'JJ'), ('.', '.')])
```

Note that you're catching the `Tree(AdvP, [('then', 'RB'), ('see', 'VB')])`,  because the tags are exactly `RB` and `VB`. So the wildcard in your grammar (i.e. `"""AdvP: {}""") in this scenario is ignored.

Also, if it's two different types of phrases, it's more advisable to use 2 labels not one. And (i think) end of string after wildcard is sort of redundant, so it's better to:

```
g = r"""
VP:{<VB.*><DT><NN.*>} 
AdvP: {<RB.*><VB.*|JJ.*|NN.*>}
"""
```

Comment: Great.. Thanks @alvas, for the help, I have removed the redundant end of string as well. Its working now.And regarding the phrase labels, I intended to keep it same, as I would like to filter out both the phrase types into one same list based on `subtree.label` later. If I mention more than one label within the list like `if subtree.node  in ("VP","AdvP")` the list is unhashable. Thats why i preferred to keep a same label for both the type of phrases. Will that bring any issue in parsing. ?

Comment: The rules mighjt be hierarchical if they are the same label. Not sure what it will do when parsing your data but it's should work I guess.

Comment: Is there a definitive guide to chunking with the NLTK regex chunker? I've had mediocre success on my data when changing the above to "{<RB.*|VB.*|JJ.*|NN.*>*}". Is the NLTK chapter (http://www.nltk.org/howto/chunk.html) really the best source?

Comment: I am also looking for a comprehensive resource for NLTK regex chunker, but the best I found so far is https://www.guru99.com/pos-tagging-chunking-nltk.html. I am still looking for a more comprehensive resource.