# How to use NLTK Regex patterns to annotate financial news with UP/DOWN indicator?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

I'm working on replicating an algorithm describe in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.11008.pdf

On the last page it describes extracting a leaf defined in the grammar labelled 'NP JJ' using the following example: Operating profit margin was 8.3%, compared to 11.8% a year earlier.

I'm expecting to see a leaf labelled 'NP JJ' but I'm not. I'm tearing my hair out as to why (relatively new to regular expressions.)

```
def split_sentence(sentence_as_string):
    ''' function to split sentence into list of words
    '''
    words = word_tokenize(sentence_as_string)

    return words

def pos_tagging(sentence_as_list):

    words = nltk.pos_tag(sentence_as_list)

    return words

def get_regex(sentence, grammar):

    sentence = pos_tagging(split_sentence(sentence));

    cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar) 

    result = cp.parse(sentence) 

    return result


example_sentence = "Operating profit margin was 8.3%, compared to 11.8% a year earlier."

grammar = """JJ : {< JJ.∗ > ∗}
            V B : {< V B.∗ >}
            NP : {(< NNS|NN >)∗}
            NP P : {< NNP|NNP S >}
            RB : {< RB.∗ >}
            CD : {< CD >}
            NP JJ : : {< NP|NP P > +(< (>< .∗ > ∗ <) >) ∗ (< IN >< DT > ∗ < RB > ∗ < JJ > ∗ < NP|NP P >) ∗ < RB > ∗(< V B >< JJ >< NP >)∗ < V B > (< DT >< CD >< NP >) ∗ < NP|NP P > ∗ < CD > ∗ < .∗ > ∗ < CD > ∗| < NP|NP P >< IN >< NP|NP P >< CD >< .∗ > ∗ <, >< V B > < IN >< NP|NP P >< CD >}"""

grammar = grammar.replace('∗','*')

tree = get_regex(example_sentence, grammar)

print(tree)
```

Comment: Odd paper, but lets try walking through =)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Alvas, really helpful. Not sure who downvoted your answer, I thought it was really intuitive.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, see [How to use nltk regex pattern to extract a specific phrase chunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090734/how-to-use-nltk-regex-pattern-to-extract-a-specific-phrase-chunk)

Lets see what's the POS tags for the sentence:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag

text = "Operating profit margin was 8.3%, compared to 11.8% a year earlier."
pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))
```

[out]:

```
[('Operating', 'NN'),
 ('profit', 'NN'),
 ('margin', 'NN'),
 ('was', 'VBD'),
 ('8.3', 'CD'),
 ('%', 'NN'),
 (',', ','),
 ('compared', 'VBN'),
 ('to', 'TO'),
 ('11.8', 'CD'),
 ('%', 'NN'),
 ('a', 'DT'),
 ('year', 'NN'),
 ('earlier', 'RBR'),
 ('.', '.')]
```

## First gotcha! No `JJ` in any of the tags

There's no `JJ` tag in any of the POS in that sentence.

## Lets head back to the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.11008.pdf

[image]

## Thinking though, the `NP JJ` isn't the ultimate goal; the ultimate goal is to produce the `UP` or `DOWN` label based on some heuristics.

Lets rephrase the steps:

1. Parse the sentence with a **parser** (in this case *regular expression parser using some sort of grammar*)
2. Identify signal that the sentence has **a pattern** that can tell use about the ultimate label.

   2a. Traverse the parse tree to extract **another pattern** that tells us about the performance indicator and numeric values.

   2b. Use the extracted extracted numeric values to determine the directionality `UP` / `DOWN` using **some heuristics**

   2c. Tag the sentence with the `UP` / `Down` identified in (2b)

## Lets see which component we can build first.

> 2b. extract **another pattern** that tells us about the performance indicator and numeric values.

We know the output to some percentage is always `CD NN` from

```
('8.3', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN')
('11.8', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN')
```

So lets try catching that in the grammar.

```
patterns = """
PERCENT: {<CD><NN>}
"""

PChunker = RegexpParser(patterns)
PChunker.parse(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
```

[out]:

```
Tree('S', [('Operating', 'NN'), ('profit', 'NN'), ('margin', 'NN'), ('was', 'VBD'), 
  Tree('PERCENT', [('8.3', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN')]), 
(',', ','), ('compared', 'VBN'), ('to', 'TO'), 
  Tree('PERCENT', [('11.8', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN')]), 
('a', 'DT'), ('year', 'NN'), ('earlier', 'RBR'), ('.', '.')])
```

Now, how do we get this:

> 2. Identify signal that the sentence has a pattern that can tell use about the ultimate label.

We know that `<PERCENT> compared to <PERCENT>` is a good pattern, so lets try to encode it.

We know that `compared to` has the tags `VBN TO` from

```
 ('8.3', 'CD'),
 ('%', 'NN'),
 (',', ','),
 ('compared', 'VBN'),
 ('to', 'TO'),
 ('11.8', 'CD'),
 ('%', 'NN'),
```

How about this:

```
patterns = """
PERCENT: {<CD><NN>}
P2P: {<PERCENT><.*>?<VB.*><TO><PERCENT>}
"""

PChunker = RegexpParser(patterns)
PChunker.parse(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
```

[out]:

```
Tree('S', [('Operating', 'NN'), ('profit', 'NN'), ('margin', 'NN'), ('was', 'VBD'), 
           Tree('P2P', [
               Tree('PERCENT', [('8.3', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN')]), 
               (',', ','), ('compared', 'VBN'), ('to', 'TO'), 
               Tree('PERCENT', [('11.8', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN')])]
               ), 
           ('a', 'DT'), ('year', 'NN'), ('earlier', 'RBR'), ('.', '.')]
    )
```

## But that pattern could have been any arbitrary number. We need a signal for the `performance indicator`

Since I'm no domain expert in the financial domain, simply using the existence of `operating profit margin` might be a good signal, i.e.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, RegexpParser

patterns = """
PERCENT: {<CD><NN>}
P2P: {<PERCENT><.*>?<VB.*><TO><PERCENT>}
"""

PChunker = RegexpParser(patterns)


text = "Operating profit margin was 8.3%, compared to 11.8% a year earlier."

indicators = ['operating profit margin']
for i in indicators:
    if i in text.lower():
        print(PChunker.parse(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))))
```

[out]:

```
(S
  Operating/NN
  profit/NN
  margin/NN
  was/VBD
  (P2P
    (PERCENT 8.3/CD %/NN)
    ,/,
    compared/VBN
    to/TO
    (PERCENT 11.8/CD %/NN))
  a/DT
  year/NN
  earlier/RBR
  ./.)
```

## Now how do we get the `UP` / `DOWN`?

> 2b. Use the extracted extracted numeric values to determine the directionality UP / DOWN using some heuristics

Just from the example sentence, other than "earlier" nothing else tells us about antecedence of the numbers.

So lets hypothesize this, if we have the pattern `PERCENT VBN TO PERCENT earlier`, we say that the 2nd percent is an older number.

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, RegexpParser

patterns = """
PERCENT: {<CD><NN>}
P2P: {<PERCENT><.*>?<VB.*><TO><PERCENT><.*>*<RBR>}
"""

def traverse_tree(tree, label=None):
    # print("tree:", tree)
    for subtree in tree:
        if type(subtree) == nltk.tree.Tree and subtree.label() == label:
            yield subtree

PChunker = RegexpParser(patterns)

parsed_text = PChunker.parse(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
for p2p in traverse_tree(parsed_text, 'P2P'):
    print(p2p)
```

[out]:

```
(P2P
  (PERCENT 8.3/CD %/NN)
  ,/,
  compared/VBN
  to/TO
  (PERCENT 11.8/CD %/NN)
  a/DT
  year/NN
  earlier/RBR)
```

## And the `UP` / `DOWN` label?

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, RegexpParser

patterns = """
PERCENT: {<CD><NN>}
P2P: {<PERCENT><.*>?<VB.*><TO><PERCENT><.*>*<RBR>}
"""

PChunker = RegexpParser(patterns)


def traverse_tree(tree, label=None):
    # print("tree:", tree)
    for subtree in tree:
        if type(subtree) == nltk.tree.Tree and subtree.label() == label:
            yield subtree

def labelme(text):
    parsed_text = PChunker.parse(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
    for p2p in traverse_tree(parsed_text, 'P2P'):
        # Check if the subtree ends with "earlier".
        if p2p.leaves()[-1] ==  ('earlier', 'RBR'):
            # Check if which percentage is larger. 
            percentages = [float(num[0]) for num in  p2p.leaves() if num[1] == 'CD']
            # Sanity check that there's only 2 numbers from our pattern.
            assert len(percentages) == 2
            if percentages[0] > percentages[1]:
                return 'DOWN'
            else:
                return 'UP'

text = "Operating profit margin was 8.3%, compared to 11.8% a year earlier."

labelme(text)
```

## Now the question begets...

**Do you want to write so many rules and catch them using the `labelme()` above? **

**Are the patterns you write foolproof?**

E.g. will there be a case that the pattern to compare percentages using the indicator and "earlier" will not be "UP" or "DOWN" as expected

**Why are we writing rules in the AI age?**

**Do you already have humanly annotated data where there are sentences and their corresponding UP/DOWN labels?** If so, let me suggest something like https://allennlp.org/tutorials or https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/notebooks/03-pipelines.ipynb